# ASP.NET MVC kendo grid make selective columns editable

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, gridview, kendo-grid

I have  a kendo grid with asp.net core mvc project. I have 7 columns but I only need two of them to be editable.

Need both the client template columns to be editable other than that everything is non editable

```
                        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<InvoiceLineViewModel>()
                    .DefaultSettings(gridSettings1, Localizer)
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {


                        var clientTemplate1 = $@"<select class='selectpicker'>
                                                                           <option>1</option>
                                                                           <option>2</option>
                                                                           <option>3</option>
                                                                           </select>
                                                                             ";


                        columns.Bound(c => c.InvoiceLineReason).ClientTemplate(clientTemplate1).Width(75).Title("Reason").Width(30);
                        var clientTemplate = $@"  <input type='text' class='form-control' asp-for='InvcAmt' />";
                        columns.Bound(c => c.Note).ClientTemplate(clientTemplate).Width(75).Title("Reason").Width(30);
                        columns.Bound(c => c.Type).Title("Type").Width(15);
                        columns.Bound(c => c.Part).Title("Part").Width(30);
                        columns.Bound(c => c.Unit).Title("Unit").Width(20);
                        columns.Bound(c => c.Quantity).Title("Quantity").Width(10);

                    }
                    ).Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Wire into the `edit` event in javascript, and conditionally set the column `attr` to `readonly` = `true`.

Like this:

```
.Events(events => events.Edit("edit"))
```

.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function edit(e) {
        if (e.model.isNew() == false) {
            $("#column1").attr("readonly", true);
        }
    }
</script>
```

See:

http://www.adambumgardner.com/blog/2015/12/17/make-a-read-only-column-in-kendo-ui-grid-edit-mode